# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() with confirmed array

Tags: php, foreach, warnings

I keep getting a warning from PHP when running the following:

```
foreach( $tags as $tag ){
   echo $tag;
}
```

I have confirmed that **$tags** is an array with both **var_dump()** and **is_array()**, but I'm still getting the warning.

The code works as intended, but with the warning filling up the Apache error log.

**$tags** **var_dump:**

```
array(2) { [0] => string(3) "Red" [1] => string(4) "Blue" }
```

Warning from error.log

```
[proxy_fcgi:error] AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /path/to/file.php on line 153
```

Comment: Can you copy & paste the warning, and var_dump the $tag in your post?

Comment: Please put here $tags variable value

Comment: I added the var_dump and the error

Answer (score 0):

Works for me in the PHP interactive shell for PHP7.

```
$ php -a
Interactive shell

php > $tags = array("red", "Blue" );
php > var_dump($tags);
array(2) {
[0]=>
string(3) "red"
[1]=>
string(4) "Blue"
}

php > foreach( $tags as $tag ){ echo $tag;};
redBlue
```

Some initial suggestions to debug your code:

- Make sure that THAT line is indeed the offending line and file where you think it is. Sometimes the server is running a different file located in a different folder, where the same line number indeed has an (old) problem, and you are looking at a fixed new file.
- Create a file with just this snippet and run it on the same machine.
- Run your code on your local machine